# Loading large videos locally, specifically in chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, osmf

I have an h264 mp4 video that is 960x540, 1000kbps and 30 minutes long. This will be playing off of a disc. I noticed **only** in chrome that when I open the web page it is embedded in, my computer slows way down and the video gets all choppy for a solid 5 seconds every time...almost like it is loading the entire resource.

I tested playing the file in IE9 and Firefox and these seem to play ok when I first open it. I really wish chrome would ditch their version of flash and just use the plugin version that all the other browsers use. I love chrome, but this is unacceptable.

I am looking for a solution to this resource loading problem. Things to note, I am using the OSMF framework and using a simple `MediaPlayerSprite` to show the video. Not a heavyweight element whatsoever. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime someone reports a problem with Flash that only occurs in Chrome, I now suspect that it is caused by the Pepper Flash player. Pepper Flash is a completely new and different plugin, and is rife with issues. You seem to be aware of this, but I just want to point out that it's not just Google repackaging Flash it's completely different code. You can disable Pepper Flash and re-enable the standard Flash plugin by going here: chrome://plugins -- find the Flash plugins list and look for the one that has "PepperFlash" in it's path and disable it.

Comment: By the way, OSMF is quite heavy. Using it in your project can bloat your SWF tremendously when compared to just using a NetConnection, NetStream, and a Video object.

Comment: I tried disabling it and that pretty much solves the issue, but I don't want to have to explain that to my clients. I am aware of the size of OSMF because of how many extra things it contains. I am using CuePoints in this particular project and cue points are that easy to do with plain ole net stream and net connection which is why I used OSMF. It has a pretty good cue point system. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Agreed! You might be able to work around some of the bugs in Pepper Flash by doing things differently in code... but for a lot of the issues I've seen with it there doesn't seem to be much recourse other than avoiding Pepper Flash until Adobe/Google address the problems. My client felt better about disabling Pepper Flash when I explained what it was and showed them how many other sites had issues with it ;) I am really curious if Adobe/Google are continuing to work on Pepper Flash at all, given the current landscape.

Comment: yeah I've had all kinds of weird bugs with pepper flash..one major issue is loading content locally. I often run into security bugs that wont allow the content to load and if you go to adjust the flash player global settings it doesn't always remember to "allowed" locations...annoying!